# Reference for set theoretic topology

Tags: reference-request

I would like to self study set-theoretic topology for research purpose. I have background in algebraic topology, complex analysis, real analysis, set theory.

May I know what are the texts should I read so that I am prepared to do research on set-theoretic topology?

Comment: See if [this Spring 2012 Peter J. Nyikos course web page](http://people.math.sc.edu/nyikos/738N.html) helps. You might also want to ask Nyikos about the status of the *textbook in progress* he mentioned.

Comment: Regarding background books besides those in set theory, useful references are [**General Topology**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486434796) by Stephen Willard (1970/2004) for basic general topology background, [**General Topology**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/3885380064) by Ryszard Engelking (1989) for a more advanced and extensive treatment of basic general topology background, and [**Set-theoretic topology**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/083570257X) by Gregory L. Naber (1977) for a little-known book that gives a transition treatment between Engelking's book and the set-theoretic topology literature.

Comment: Since Naber's book doesn't seem to be reviewed by MR or Zbl, I thought I should give more details. Gregory Lawrence Naber (1948-___), **Set-Theoretic Topology with Emphasis on Problems from the Theory of Coverings, Zero Dimensionality and Cardinal Invariants**, University Microfilms International, 1977, xvi + 706 pages. [Review by Mary Ellen Rudin](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1978-84-02/S0002-9904-1978-14471-1/S0002-9904-1978-14471-1.pdf) -- **Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society** 84 #2 (March 1978), pp. 271-272 (review of Naber's book is on p. 272).